# Solr - Regular Expression to create field for case insensitive term completion field

Tags: solr, case-insensitive

In the solr community it is suggested that the best approach to do case insensitive term completion (while retaining original case in facet) on filter/facet values is to index the content in the form "lowercasevalue|OriginalCaseValue" such that the prefixing can match on the first part while the displayed value can be the OriginalCase value.

I would like to attain this on any field by utilizing a fieldType that would construct the value via solr.PatternRepaceFilters.  how would I write a pattern replace filter that would turn "MyValue" into "myvalue|MyValue" for a field being indexed as myfield:MyValue.  But term completed/faceted on myfield_tc:myvalue|MyValue?

```
<fieldType name="termCompleteField" class="solr.StrField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" ????????? />
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you replace

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" ????????? />
```

with

```
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
```

and add a copyfield termCompleteField_lowercase with this new fieldtype?